# Error occurring while Listing wsdl from wso2 governance

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have added wso2 governance registry on wso2 BPS 3 as a feature from http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/
and restarted. 
When tried to add wsdl from file it giving error:

org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Attribute Search Service not Found.

I am trying to use BPS, GREG as a single component to reduce servers in my project. After GREG added as a feature it adding ".wsdl" file at "_/system/governance" and it is not forming endpoints,services as GREG normally do.

Is there any way to get out of this problem.

Thank's in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is missing some of the features which needed in ordered to work governance features. I think best option is using Governance Registry separately and mount the registry of it to BPS. By doing this you can add services from Governance Registry and use them in BPS. You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details) document for more information on registry mounting.